# Websphere 8.5 : Using multiple TLS version for outbound

Tags: security, websphere

I am working on configuring multiple TLS version in websphere bpm 8.5.6 .i have selected SSL_TLSV2 to use all tls versions. I am able to see the configuration updated on ssl.client.props file after restart.

But still calls from websphere are rejected by salesforce

> UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https

Can anyone help me in configuring multiple tls version through which i can use tls 1.0 and 1.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please confirm if you have updated both the default SSL Configurations: `CellDefaultSSLSettings` & `NodeDefaultSSLSettings`. Both these configurations take effect at different scopes.

Comment: What API do you use to make the outbound connection?